# Disable personalization on Google Signin button

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have a "Sign In With Google" button in my project, added like this:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "client_id_here",
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("googleButtonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
        );
        google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
    }
</script>
```

This works fine, but when the user has an active Google account, it says '`Sign In As *name*`'. My client doesn't want this.

How can I disable this personalization and always show the text "`Sign In With Google`" in the button?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button), if you set the "size" attribute on the button to "medium" or "small" then it won't show the personalised version.

Comment: Sometimes a simple answer is the best -- worked for me!